# Get only words start and end with either letters or digits using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract words from a sentence using regular expression with following condition

- Words should start and end with letters or digits

For example i am trying on the sentence

```
>> text = 'This product labelled as 4KJ2 with manufactured in P&G in the year 1990 : symbols $$$, $J2, 2J$'
>> re.findall(r'[\w(\S)\d]{2,}', text)   # this re pattern i applied
```

But the result is

```
>> ['This',
    'product',
    'labelled',
    'as',
    '4KJ2',
    'with',
    'manufactured',
    'in',
    'P&G',
    'in',
    'the',
    'year',
    '1990',
    'symbols',
    '$$$,',
    '$J2,',
    '2J$']
```

In the above output

```
$$$, $J2, 2J$
```

are not desired words in the output.
I have tried below re pattern also but didn't work

```
>> re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9][\S]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$', text)
>> [] # empty ouput
```

-Thanks

Comment: you could first of all split the sentence into a list with `"text".split()` and then run your regex on each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*[a-zA-Z0-9](?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oiQT66/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5QT7ij)

**Note** that the minimum length is 2 characters.

If you also want to match a single char, you could use an optional non capturing group after matching the first char:

```
(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\S*[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/myHuG9/1)

For example

```
import re

text = 'This product labelled as 4KJ2 with manufactured in P&G in the year 1990 : symbols $$$, $J2, 2J$'
result = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*[a-zA-Z0-9](?!\S)', text)
print(result)
```

Output

```
['This', 'product', 'labelled', 'as', '4KJ2', 'with', 'manufactured', 'in', 'P&G', 'in', 'the', 'year', '1990', 'symbols']
```

Comment: @Bhaskar: If it works for you, consider accepting and/or upvoting the answers that helped you.

Comment: Sorry Jan, I forgot to accept answer, Thank you for the all your support

Answer (score 3):

A non-regex solution could be

```
text = "This product labelled as 4KJ2 with manufactured in P&G in the year 1990 : symbols $$$, $J2, 2J$"

def tester(word):
    if word[:1].isalnum() and word[-1].isalnum():
        return True
    return False

words = [word for word in text.split() if tester(word)]
print(words)
```

This yields

```
['This', 'product', 'labelled', 'as', '4KJ2', 'with', 'manufactured', 'in', 'P&G', 'in', 'the', 'year', '1990', 'symbols']
```

Comment: Thank you Jan, It works for me but I had to use only regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string before using a regex with `"some text".split()` to ease up things e.g.

```py
text = 'This product labelled as 4KJ2 with manufactured in P&G '\
       'in the year 1990 : symbols $$$, $J2, 2J$ $abc def g'

[x for x in text.split() if re.match("^\w(?:.*\w)?$", x)]
```

Here is a quite compact regex, but it doesn't work for a valid string at the end of a sentence:

```py
re.findall(r'\b(\w\S*?\w)(?=\s)', text)
```

This one will work, but i guess using the list comprehension will work much better.

```py
re.findall(r'(?:\s|\A)(\w(?:\S*\w)?)(?=\s|$|[.,:;?!])', text)
```

`\b` matches a word boundary

`(?=\s)` is a positive lookahead, which will check for a space to follow the match without including it.

As @Toto just pointed out `\w` will match word characters including digits.

Here is my example on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nUz989/1) as well.

Comment: `[\w\d]` is better written `\w`

Comment: It doesn't match a word at end of the string, but matches `abc` in `$abc`

Comment: I just saw that! the alternative solution with the list comprehension doesn't have this problem. Thanks for the notice I'll have a look into it.

Comment: Than you for the response

Comment: I just updated the answer to work for all the test cases given.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
(?<=[\s^])[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

At least it works on regex101.com.

It should look behind for either white space or beginning of a sentence and match letters or numbers explicitly.
It should work with \w, too, but it's hard to use that site on a phone.

Comment: This doesn't really do what you think it does. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/Hz1Dl3/2)

Comment: A caret in a character class, not at the beginning, means, well, ... a caret.

Comment: Than you edd for the response,it is not working as i want